# Reading a local text file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I just started learning JavaScript and I have a small problem. I have a text file with some text in it. I can read the content of the text file in browser (I mean in .hta) but the text appears as a single line. I want to add line breaks to each line. How do I do that?

**Text file content:**
I want to live where soul meets body
And let the sun wrap its arms around me
...

**JS:**

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\myJS\\test.txt", 1, false, 0);
var fText = txtFile.Read(1000);
document.write(fText);
txtFile.Close();
fso = null;
```

**The output:**
I want to live where soul meets body And let the sun wrap its arms around me ...

Any advice, suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because HTML doesn't recognize linebreaks in the text file. You need to add some HTML to your output. Something like this:

```
function readFile (path) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
        iStream=fso.OpenTextFile(path, 1, false);
    while(!iStream.AtEndOfStream) {
        document.body.innerHTML += iStream.ReadLine() + '<br/>';
    }        
    iStream.Close();
}
```

This function reads the whole file. If you want to read exactly 1000 lines, you can use a `for` loop, but you'll need to check that the file is not shorter than 1000 lines by using `AtEndOfStream` property.

Just take care of this function is invoked within `body`tag, or in a `window.onload` handler. Notice, that my code uses DOM manipulation instead of `document.write()`.

Comment: Hmm. Its either I'm doing something wrong or this doesn't work =\

Comment: @akinuri OOPS, I'm sorry, I used a wrong property in the loop condition, I've corrected the code.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It doesn't print anything. Can you try and see if it prints anything? Forget line breaks, I don't even know if its going to print the text. And it seems it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm... It seems I'd better go to sleep... Now the code is OK, just corrected the `ActiveX` call. I've also tested the code, and it works now.