# Reading through a local text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, io, plaintext

So I have a text file, let's call it `plaintext.txt`, and it's stored locally and I'm trying to read it in javascript, from the same folder that my js is running from.

In my html, I have

```
<script id="plaintext" src="plaintext.txt" type="text/plain"></script>
```

In my js I have

```
var text = document.getElementById('plaintext').textContent;
```

When running it I get the error in the console (warning?)

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///path/to/file/plaintext.txt".
```

And I just get a blank `string`.

*I just want to get the text from this file!!!!* What am I doing wrong? Am I incorrect to think that this can be done this way? Is there a way to do this without using any external libraries like jQuery? I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm kind of astounded how hard it is just to read a local file! (though I do understand the security risks)

Comment: Seems you don't have a server. You may want to look into this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: This answer is pretty great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760852/how-to-access-plain-text-content-retrieved-via-script-type-text-plain-src

Comment: Passerby - tried with server, same results. Bill- so that answer is telling me that it's not possible to read a file as plain text from a local directory? Any suggestions for alternatives? Putting the text inline would suck because it's quite large (6000+ lines)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of:

```
<script id="plaintext" src="plaintext.txt" type="text/plain"></script>
```

Script tags are meant for loading scripts, not plain text files.
Maybe [Reading a local text file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589700/reading-a-local-text-file-in-javascript) could be of some use to you. Otherwise go server side (which is much more convenient in your case), especially if you want to handle large amounts of data. So instead of storing everything in a file, you could store it in a database instead. If you're interested, go install Netbeans and get an MySQL database. [Tutorialpoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/) is a great resource for learning java server page , sql, etc. Hope this helps :).

Comment: Server-side isn't an option, as I'm doing stuff with WebGL (file being loaded is a 3D model)
Also, that answer you linked to uses ActiveX. Isn't that kind of a big no-no?

Comment: Well, you could emit the ActiveX part because only IE is dependent on it. Personally, lately I really don't care if something works for IE or not. IE is a terrible browser, and people are better of using a browser like Firefox for ultimate functionality, and statistically people are moving away from IE anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing this with jQuery, using the example that can be found at [jquery - Read a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981815/jquery-read-a-text-file)