# CSV to Graph in HTA Application

Tags: javascript, html, csv, vbscript, hta

So I made an HTA app where I have a button which runs test scripts, which eventually dumps the result in a CSV file. The `onclick` for the button is in VBScript and I am trying to get the same function to generate a graph from the CSV once the tests have completed running.

What I am trying to do is call a JavaScript function that would read from, and generate a graph from the CSV file after the file is passed into it as an argument, but the call has to be made from the VBScript `onclick` function.I have tried to use a few JavaScript functions but none of them seems to be meant for a local HTA App with a call from VBScript.

Here is the code snippet from the HTA app showing the JavaScript functions I tried to use and the `onclick` VBScript function that I tried to call them from:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadCSV(file) {
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    // load
    request.open('GET', file, false);
    request.send();
    parseCSV(request.responseText);
}

function parseCSV(data) {
    //split into rows
    var rows = data.split("n"); 
    // loop through all rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // this line helps to skip empty rows
        if (rows[i]) {
            // our columns are separated by comma
            var column = rows[i].split(",");

            // column is array now
            var proc = column[0];
            // second item is value of the second column
            var value = column[1];

            // create object which contains all these items:
            var dataObject = {
                process: proc,
                result: value
            };
            // add object to chartData array
            chartData.push(dataObject);
        }
    }
}

function showChart(){
    chart.validateData();
}
</script>
```

```vb
<script language="VBScript">
Function RunScript()
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ScriptArea.innerhtml = "Checking for dependencies, please wait.."
    return = WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Scripts/PCPT.ps1", 0, true)
    ScriptArea.innerhtml = "Running MS Word Test, please wait.."
    return = WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Scripts/Word_Test.ps1", 0, true)
    ScriptArea.innerhtml = "Running MS Excel Test, please wait.."
    return = WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Scripts/Excel_Test.ps1", 0, true)
    ScriptArea.innerhtml = "Running MS PowerPoint Test, please wait.."
    return = WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Scripts/PPT_Test.ps1", 0, true)
    return = WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Scripts/Process_Results.ps1", 0, true)
    ScriptArea.innerhtml = "All tests complete"
    LoadCSV("comparison.csv")
    showChart()    
End Function   
</script>
```

The CSV file I'm trying to pass is called "comparison.csv". You'll see at the end of the `RunScript` function that I'm calling the `LoadCSV("comparison.csv")` where I try to pass in the file. I got an error in that function because it's not able to get the file from my PC (`request.open('GET', file, false);`), probably due to a permission issue. I am open to suggestions that would use an entirely different method to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Ansgar thanks for helping out a newbie and polishing up my question! hoping to get answers soon.

Comment: Most likely the filesystem doesn't respond to HTTP requests. Try with a [`FileSystemObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15590246/1630171).